# Where can I find a list of all the model aircraft flying fields in the USA?

Tags: resources, flying-fields

Is there a comprehensive list of model flying fields that have operated or have been developed in the United States?  I assume the AMA has some of this data, but I am curious if there is a larger list that designates all places to fly both past and present?  Present is fine if past is too big an ask.

Comment: Recommend a mod add flying-fields or fields to the list of tags?

Comment: I approve the tag request! :) On that, you make a good point.

Comment: Thanks. I’m waiting the 40 minutes to ask another question and i’m finding more tags that would help.  Like Mavic or Mavic-1 (pro) original is missing.  Guess i’ll have to get to 150.  :D.  Really excited for this beta.  Very useful in an ever changing hobby.

Comment: It isn't official, but this might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_model_airplane_fields

Comment: That is a good start to a list. It is missing a lot of fields.  I didn’t see Apollo 11 field in LA or TRCC in Tucson. No Buttonwillow. No Fontana. I checked out the rcgroups places link too.  It didn’t work on my phone .  Thanks for that resource!  Can’t wait to find some more suggestions and options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does not exist, a few reasons.

1. AMA lists most of their fields, but that information is spotty and I have almost been arrested trying to fly at listed AMA sites that are not valid.
2. FAA has this list, but they have openly admitted that infrastructure and management problems have led to this data being in decay and not very useful.  This problem was exposed as 107 was coming into law and many commercial pilots raised a stink because airports on flight maps were never (EVER) updated, this led to LAANC and the apps becoming more of an authority.
3. No one shares spots. There have been several apps that try to get people to share and they all went belly up real fast.

This information ALL exists in the FAA, but their data is horrible (I work with this info, total nightmare).  Most of the good fields are private and invite only in my world. We run a few spots and you will be shot dead if you fly there with out permission (not an exaggeration, I often carry when flying).

Airmap and Kittyhawk will have reasonably good current AMA type fields.  That data is the best for "free".  You may want to check with [Snowflake](http://snowflakesoftware.com/), but their data feed (last time I was involved) starts at $5k/year.

It should be noted that the FAAn NTSB, FBI, and other orgs all recognize the unstructured, uncoordinated, and non-unified nature of RC flight and use this to control airspace.  I mention this because there is considerable history on the record of the FAA trying to wipe all drone use from NAS and this is a declared strategy and we have seen it in action.  Dig into the DC restrictions of 2014-15 to understand why the FAA is an advisory and not an ally.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I understand the FAA is a regulator that is intended to promote safety in civil and military aviation.  I do hope the future hold safe operations for civilian remote operations and safe skys for everyone. Private pilots are also somewhat unstructured when it comes to the recommendations of the FAA.  Organized chaos up there.

Comment: Can you let me know some of the failed apps you mentioned?

Comment: @cliffclof The one that comes to mind first is AJ Torres's "Where2fly", died about 2 years ago. There used to be several localized google maps with locations but that trend is gone.  Airmap and Kittyhawk will you to broadcast and no one uses it (sure, there's like 3 drones in the air in the USA...right).  There used to be more, but they were clearly vaporware.

Comment: Also @cliffclof we (as in advocacy groups I work with) have busted the FAA for cooking the books on safety. Gary Mortimer and Patrick Egan at SUAS News are who you want to follow. Here's an intro https://www.suasnews.com/2020/03/has-general-aviation-just-shot-itself-in-the-foot/. The FAA is no longer the arbiter of safety per the congressional charter. Now the FAA has internal management, data, and lobby (Boeing Max) problems.  Internal gridlock is prohibiting any meaningful operation where they are unable to formulate regs, lack enforcement, and it gets worse, out of characters, be scared.

Comment: Thanks for the links and info.  Good stuff.  I’m firm on self regulated drone use with logged flights.  I think education and safe access to the sky is important to promote good flying practices in the future.   I don’t think the FAA has ever been the regulator.  Even a commercial airline that lands on a taxiway gets, call tower @ xxx-xxx-xxxx.